# CultureInfo.CurrentCulture does not contain the correct value --> numberformat problems

Tags: c#, csv, double, number-formatting, currentculture

I need to write doubles to a csv file in a wpf mvvm application.
These doubles are originally strings set in invariant culture.
I recieve them like so from the server side application and parse them with

```
bool result = double.TryParse(row[0], NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out value);
```

However when I try to write them to the csv file (either with `"" + value`, `value.ToString()`, `value.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)` or `value.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)`), the current culture seems to be EN-US while it should be NL (dutch). My browser settings, windows settings, keyboard settings... are all set to dutch, so when I check my regional number settings it contains the decimal separator ",", but my application separates the decimals with "." since the culture is EN-US.

So when I write my csv file and open it in excel it contains decimal values separated with "." instead of ",".
This way my excel does not see these values as decimal values since they are not in the excel number culture/my windows settings culture.

Does anyone know what's going on?

**Edit**

Just to be clear. I'm not looking for a way to set the culture hard coded. I specifically need the culture set in windows, the one which excel uses.

Comment: Have you tried Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture? What's in there?

Comment: @GerrieSchenck `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` will affect how resources are loaded, not formatting. I guess you mean `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`?

Comment: @Fredrik Mörk I didn't know that, I usually use it to do formatting.

Comment: The OP means the `CurrentCulture` is already `dutch`, you should try checking to be sure if it's `dutch` (of course in your code).

Comment: @GerrieSchenck We're drifting off-topic here, but in short: if you call `ToString` without specifying culture, it will use `CurrentCulture` for formatting automatically. If you call `ToString` and pass `CurrentUICulture` to the method, that culture will of course be used.

Comment: It gives me the same result. If my perception is correct by the way, I think `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` is the same as the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` one, no? In fact, every single culture I can think off that is read-only in the system gives me En-US as a result: CurrentCulture, CurrentUICulture, InstalledUICulture...

Comment: On a side note: My display language is actually English, but everything else (datetime, keyboard, system language...) is dutch. So I'm guessing the UICulture being En-US might make sense, but not the CurrentCulture and especially not the NumberFormat used inside.

Answer (score 0):

For further reference here's what the problem was:

We have a pretty large application where it is possible to override the culture for datetime display etc... Once you set the current thread culture to a new culture, the original one cannot be accessed anymore.

So to be able to access the windows culture I created a property which remembers the currentculture before it was changed to the user setting of the application and used that one to export my data to a csv file.

Answer (score -1):

Have you override **base.InitializeCulture()**;

below sample code is just for understanding..may be you get some idea

```
    if (Session["CurrentUI"] != null)
    {
        String selectedLanguage = (string)Session["CurrentUI"];
        UICulture = selectedLanguage;
        Culture = selectedLanguage;

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
            CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(selectedLanguage);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new
            CultureInfo(selectedLanguage);
    }

    base.InitializeCulture();
```

Comment: Thank you for trying, but it's hardly an answer since I have no session, nor an InitializeCulture for the session...